# Установка библиотеки libstdc++ из исходников

Tags: gcc, c++, linux

Мне необходимо собрать библиотеку libstdc++ под стендовый компьютер с архитектурой SPARC. На нём уже есть очень старая версия gcc (3.4.6). Я пробовал искать данную библиотечку find / -name "libstdc++*", но она не установлена. Мои C++ программы, собранные с помощью кросс компилятора требуют её наличия (что не удивительно):

> error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Я пробовал искать данную библиотечку `find / -name "libstdc++*"`, но она не установлена. Я скачал tar'ы: `gcc-g++-3.4.6.tar.bz2` с различных зеркал, например отсюда. Распаковал архив и пробую установить, запуском:

```
./configure
```

, но получаю следующую ошибку:

```
configure: error: cannot find install-sh or install.sh in . ./.. ./../..
```

Причём такое происходит с различными архивами. В чём тут проблема? Каким-то другим способом может устанавливается? У меня плохо с английским с сожалению и я толком не понимаю как правильно нужно ставить. Вот есть, как я понял, [manual по установке](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~etsman/Docs/gcc-3.4-base/libstdc++/html/install.html). Я так понимаю, что нужно связать мою установку с уже установленным g++. Потому что сам компилятор g++ есть, нет определённых библиотек.
Спасибо заранее за помощь.

Comment: А разве нельзя установить нормально g++ и libstdc++ из репозиториев Вашей ОС?

Кстати, какая ОС?

Comment: А понял: Ваша прога требует 6-ую версию, а установлена более ранняя. А разве нельзя просто перекомпилировать на этом компе?

Comment: там своя сборка ОС и репозиториев нет, различных packadge manager'ов тоже нет

Comment: никакой версии libstdc++ вообще нет

Comment: А какая ОС? Линукс, *BSD или Solaris?

Comment: По-моему, проще поставить заново нормальную систему, чем так мучиться.

Comment: Операционка linux

Comment: поставить заново не получится, неужели так сложно собрать либу ?

Comment: Для начала сделайте dummy install.sh и положите его куда configure хочет. Может пройдет и создаст Makefile. 

Тогда (если make пройдет и сделает библиотеку) make install, конечно же, не пройдет. Вот тут надо поискать в инете, как и куда на Вашей системе записать собранный .so . 

Где-то когда-то я видел инструкции по установке в систему собственной библиотеки в разных ОС.

Answer (score 1):

> Мои C++ программы, собранные с помощью кросс компилятора требуют её наличия (что не удивительно)

Если вы смогли собрать свои программы кросс-компилятором, 
значит эта библиотека есть в составе кросс-компилятора,
просто найдите ее и положите ее рядом с программой, а потом:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd` ./my-program
```